# VBA cannot display pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, displayobject, vba

I am trying to automate a report. The first step is to create a pivot table, and I think the pivot table is being created but I cannot view it on the sheet.

```
 Sub CurrentPipelineView()
 Dim pt As PivotTable
 Dim ptcache As PivotCache
 Dim pf As PivotField
 Dim pi As PivotItem
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim wspivot As Worksheet
 Dim datasheetname As String
 Dim totalrows As Integer
 Dim tottalcolumns As Integer

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
  If ws.Name = "PivotTest1" Then
  ws.Delete
  End If
  Next


 'Setting sheet names
  SheetName = "Data" 'storing sheet name which will be default
  Set ws = Worksheets(SheetName)
  Sheets.Add.Name = "PivotTest1"
  Set wspivot = Worksheets("PivotTest1")
  wspivot.Select 'Activating worksheet


 'Delete any prior pivot tables
  On Error Resume Next
  For Each CurrentViewPt In wspivot.PivotTables
    CurrentViewPt.TableRange2.Clear
Next CurrentViewPt

 'Defining pivot table cache
  ws.Select
  totalcolumns = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  totalrows = ws.Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count 'Counting           total rows
  Set PRange = ws.Range("A1").Offset(totalrows, totalcolumns)
  Set ptcache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, PRange)


  'Create pivot table
   wspivot.Select
   Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add(ptcache, Range("A3"), "PipelineView")

   End Sub
```

What I want to do is take the data from the first sheet which will be generated from the database and use that to make reports.

To make the correct pivot I want to debug the code field by field to ensure that I am adding correct fields. When i run this I cannot see the pivot table on the sheet, like i would if I was doing it manually in excel.

Thanks and Regards
varun

Comment: put the following instruction `On Error GoTo 0` right after `Next CurrentViewPt` to check the line where you have problem. And give us information which line it is.

Comment: Died at set pt
      Set ptcache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, PRange)

Comment: First of all, did you checked variables: `totalrows` & `totalcolumns` if they differ from 0 when debugging error?

Comment: totalrows and totalcolumns is getting right value, so is PRange but ptcache is the problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the code finally working. Used PivotTableWizard instead of adding/creating a pivotcache.

Below is my code. Also found a function .UsedRange for selecting the used ranges

```
Public Sub CountingRows()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim SheetName As String 'data sheet name
Dim TotalRows As Integer 'counts total number of rows
Dim TotalColumns As Integer 'sets total number of columns
Dim Counter As Integer 'Counter to start the loop
Dim wsPivot As Worksheet
Dim CreatePt As PivotTable 'creates using pivot table wizard
Dim CurrentViewPt As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim PTCache As PivotCache
Dim PF As PivotField

'Deleting sheet if it already exists
   For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
   If ws.Name = "PivotTest1" Then
     ws.Delete
    End If
    Next

'Setting sheet names
SheetName = "Sheet 1" 'storing sheet name which will be default
 Set ws = Worksheets(SheetName)
Sheets.Add.Name = "PivotTest1"
 Set wsPivot = Worksheets("PivotTest1")
wsPivot.Select 'Activating worksheet

 'Delete any prior pivot tables
On Error Resume Next
For Each CurrentViewPt In wsPivot.PivotTables
    CurrentViewPt.TableRange2.Clear
Next CurrentViewPt

'Defining pivot table cache
 ws.Select
TotalColumns = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Counting total columns
TotalRows = ws.Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count 'Counting total rows
Set PRange = ws.UsedRange 'found a new function to use do not need to use above fields, but keeping them just incase
'Set PRange = ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(TotalRows, TotalColumns)<<<Not sure if it works>>>
wsPivot.Select
 Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)


'Create the Pivot Table
 Set CreatePt = wsPivot.PivotTableWizard(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange, TableDestination:=wsPivot.Range("B4"), TableName:="CurrentNBI")
 Set CurrentViewPt = wsPivot.PivotTables("CurrentNBI")

'**** Define the layout of the pivot table****
 With CurrentViewPt.PivotFields("NBI_CODE")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
  End With
   With CurrentViewPt.PivotFields("CREATION_DATE")
   .Orientation = xlRowField
   .Position = 2
   End With
   With CurrentViewPt.PivotFields("BUSINESS_AREA")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
   .Position = 3
   End With
 With CurrentViewPt.PivotFields("CASE_CLASSIFICATION")
   .Orientation = xlRowField
   .Position = 4
End With
With CurrentViewPt.PivotFields("BOOKING_CENTER")
   .Orientation = xlRowField
   .Position = 5
 End With
With CurrentViewPt.PivotFields("LOCATION")
   .Orientation = xlRowField
   .Position = 6
 End With
With CurrentViewPt.PivotFields("INITIATIVE_NAME")
   .Orientation = xlRowField
   .Position = 7
End With
With CurrentViewPt.PivotFields("BRIEF_DESCRIPTION")
   .Orientation = xlRowField
   .Position = 8
 End With
With CurrentViewPt.PivotFields("TARGET_ASSESSMENT_DATE")
   .Orientation = xlRowField
   .Position = 9
End With
With CurrentViewPt.PivotFields("ASSESSMENT_COMPLETION_DATE")
   .Orientation = xlRowField
   .Position = 10
 End With
 With CurrentViewPt.PivotFields("NBI_CODE")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 1
    .xlCount = True
 End With


 'Setting sub-totals to zero
  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("CurrentNBI").PivotFields("NBI_CODE").Subtotals = _
    Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
 ActiveSheet.PivotTables("CurrentNBI").PivotFields("CREATION_DATE").Subtotals = _
    Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
 ActiveSheet.PivotTables("CurrentNBI").PivotFields("BUSINESS_AREA").Subtotals = _
    Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("CurrentNBI").PivotFields("CASE_CLASSIFICATION").Subtotals = _
    Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("CurrentNBI").PivotFields("BOOKING_CENTER").Subtotals = _
    Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("CurrentNBI").PivotFields("LOCATION").Subtotals = _
    Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("CurrentNBI").PivotFields("INITIATIVE_NAME").Subtotals = _
    Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is the `PRange` object - it's just setting to the lower-right cell in the field.  Try changing that to:

```
Set PRange = Range(ws.Range("A1"), ws.Range("A1").Offset(totalrows, totalcolumns))
```

I'd also use `ptcache.CreatePivotTable(...)` to create the PivotTable:

```
Set pt = ptcache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=wspivot.Range("A3"), TableName:="YourTableName")
```

**EDIT:**

Use this to set PRange:

```
Set prange = Range(ws.Range("A1"), ws.Range("A1").Offset(totalrows, totalcolumns - 1))
```

The issue with my code was it was adding an extra column (which was blank), and that will throw an error.

Comment: also tried Set PRange = ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(TotalRows, TotalColumns)